# How to enable a UWP app open via a hyperlink (Deep-linking)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, deep-linking, windows-10-universal

I have followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking) and implemented "apps for websites using app URI handlers". However, the link only works when it's embedded in another app like Mail app, Microsoft Teams or Skype, etc...

What I want is to open the UWP app when the link is clicked inside a browser. Preferably, the email is opened in the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and the user clicks on the link in the email body and then the UWP app opens automatically and continues the flow.

Why this deep linking is supported by other apps but not via the browser?

Json file hosted in [here](https://boardpac-cms-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/windows-app-web-link) and `appUriHandler` is added as follows:

```
<uap3:Extension Category="windows.appUriHandler">
  <uap3:AppUriHandler>
      <uap3:Host Name="boardpac-cms-dev.azurewebsites.net" />
  </uap3:AppUriHandler>
</uap3:Extension>
```

And a sample link to open the app that comes in the email is like this:

> https://boardpac-cms-dev.azurewebsites.net/applink/resetpassword?token=ODFDR3M0MUZadWE0&tn=iot1&tid=96&redirectUrl=http%3a%2f%2f192.168.25.109%3a4049%2fiot1%2fpassword%2fresetpassword%3ftoken%3dODFDR3M0MUZadWE

I have done the [validations locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking#test-it-out-local-validation-tool) and it does not show any sign of an error.
Appreciate your support to figure this out.

**Update:**
In Windows settings, there is a section that shows the app is ready to launch via the browser as well. Too bad it's not working.
[image]

Comment: What browser are you testing? Is it Microsoft Edge? The official document mentions **“Starting with the Windows 10 Creators update, supported links clicked in Microsoft Edge will launch the corresponding app. Supported links clicked in other browsers (for example, Internet Explorer, etc.), will keep you in the browsing experience.”** Therefore, I suggest you could use the specified Microsoft Edge browser to check whether this issue also occurs.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Hi, My OS version is 19042.867 and the Edge version is 91.0.864.41. The UWP app is targeted (Min and target) to version 1809 (17763). I have tested on few famous browsers including edge with their latest versions. Nothing works.

Comment: I also tried the debug and release versions of the apps installed. No results.

Comment: Could you please try [Web validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking#test-it-web-validation) to check whether it works?

Comment: With Windows Key + R to open the Run dialog box and paste one of the supported URL it works. I don't understand why it is not works in the web browser.

Comment: We are consulting other engineers about your issue, there might be some delay.

Comment: Does this issue happen on another device? Could you please try to test it on another PC to check whether this issue also occurs?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Hi, tried on couple of other pc’s. Issue exists.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Hi, Do you have any updates on this?