# How can I get deep linking to work on UWP from a browser?

Tags: uwp, deep-linking

I have a UWP app (Xamarin) and I am trying to get Universal linking to work.
It works fine in the Android and iOS builds (same code)
On UWP the app will launch if I place the url in Windows+R command or use LaunchApiAsync() from an app.

This topic was discussed here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966994/how-to-enable-a-uwp-app-open-via-a-hyperlink-deep-linking?newreg=f27d372927b546c3933cb4b02413926f](https://stackoverflow.com) without resolution.

I need it to work from a browser that will load the app if it is installed and otherwise access my web service which in turn launches the windows app store.

I have created and validated the windows-app-web-link which looks like this.

```
[{
     "packageFamilyName" : "Your app's package family name, e.g MyApp_9jmtgj1pbbz6e",  
     "paths" : [ "myapp/myendpoint" ]  
}]
```

I know that this works because it launches from the windows run command. Including presenting the app store if the app is not yet installed.

I would expect it to work from a browser. I read somewhere that should work from Edge on the later Windows 10 builds. I am running windows 11 and can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is same to this thread:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/989826/app-for-websites-using-app-uri-handlers-doesnt-wor

This question was discussed with UWP Team before. We think there is likely some underlying integration between the OS and Edge that made this work, and this problem is more related to Edge or Chorme, not UWP.

If you want to get more information like a solution or a conclusion about this issue, you can refer to [Roy Li - MSFT‘s answer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/989826/app-for-websites-using-app-uri-handlers-doesnt-wor)

There is still no update on GitHub Issues:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-dev-docs/issues/2573
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-dev-docs/issues/2848